# When I add users to a Security Group using Powershell, they don't show up in AD

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I have a script which has the following for adding users using a CSV file, in Powershell. Windows Server 2008 R2.

looks like this:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\me\Desktop\users.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Name} |`
 ForEach-Object {`
New-ADUser `
-Name $_."Name" `
-GivenName $_."GivenName" `
-Surname $_."Surname" `
-Description $_."Department" `
-SamAccountName $_."Logon_Username" `
-UserPrincipalName $_."UPN" `
-DisplayName $_."Display_Name" `
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "P@ssw0rd1!" -Force) `
-Path "OU=Users,OU=Head Office,OU=International,DC=company,DC=com" `
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
-Enabled $true | Enable-ADAccount | `
Add-ADGroupMember "QA_Users" $_."Logon_Username";
}
```

the script goes through successfully with no error, and the users are added. when I go to AD Users and Computers, I can see the users added correctly. However, when I go to the 'member of' section, it doesn't show the group specified in the script.

I've noticed then if I try to add the user again manually by powershell using add-adgroupmember, the command says 'user is already part of the specified group'.

I've noticed if I wait about 15-20 minutes, then the group will show up. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Group membership changes are not classified for urgent replication so it is normal to see the delay. Maybe you can use the -Server switch to point to the same DC that you are viewing in ADUC and you will be able to view the change instantly.

Comment: @Bin, This should be an answer.  Your recommendation to scope changes and queries to a specific server would totally solve OP's issue.  Totally.

Answer (score 5):

Group membership changes are not classified for urgent replication so it is normal to see the delay. Maybe you can use the `-Server` switch to point to the same DC that you are viewing in ADUC and you will be able to view the change instantly.

Comment: I tried this unfortunately, still no luck :(

Comment: @2legit2quit I just tested this and it does work immediately. Can you share your updated code?